# Split javascript file into multiple files that share functions and variables

Tags: javascript, html

I’m currently working on a web app, and my `index.js` file is getting too big and confusing, and I was wondering what the best way is to split it into multiple JS files that share variables and functions?

I want to use only pure JavaScript, I tried to link both JS files in the HTML file but they don’t share the variables.

Comment: See [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your file with the variables being referenced is linked first. Once a script is loaded, globally-scoped variables should be accessible to any later script.

For example, you might have a .js file containing data stored in JSON format, or as an object. That file should be linked to first, then any other .js files that reference that data should follow it.

You can also use [import and export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) to allow files to be modular and reference each other.  If you're working with many files or on a very large web app, this is the way to go.  For simpler projects, you can probably get away with the previous option.